# What is the purpose of grant_type parameter in OAuth 2 Authentication

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, lumen

I am using OAuth 2 Authentication in Lumen microframework. Right now i am using the `grant_type` value is `password`. It throws `unsupported_grant_type`, If i am using something different. I want to know the purpose of using `grant_type` is `password`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `grant_type` URL parameter is required by [OAuth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-73) for the `/token` endpoint, which exchanges a grant for real tokens. So the OAuth2 server knows what you are sending to it. You are using the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-37), so you must specify it with the value `password`.

From the OAuth2 RFC:

> An authorization grant is a credential representing the resource
> owner's authorization (to access its protected resources) used by the
> client to obtain an access token.

The `grant_type=password` means that you are sending a username and a password to the `/token` endpoint. If you used the [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-24) flow, you could use the value `authorization_code`. But then you don't send the username+password pair, but a code received from the OAuth2 server after user authentication. The code is an arbitrary string - not human readable. It's nicely shown in the workflow diagrams in the RFC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also i want to know what is the differents between `authorization_code` and `password`. if anything else like custom value, can we use for `grant_type`?

Comment: Sorry, my original answer was not correct, so I edited it and included the `authorization_code` info.

Answer (score 1):

in OAuth 2.0, the term “grant type” refers to the way an application gets an access token. OAuth 2.0 defines several grant types, including the authorization code flow. OAuth 2.0 extensions can also define new grant types.