# How to authenticate an Azure EventGrid API Connection using a script?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template, azureportal, azure-eventgrid

I am creating an EventGrid API Connection using an ARM Template. It gets created successfully, however, i still have to authenticate it by hand via Azure Portal.

Here is my ARM Template:

```
    "resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
        "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('azureEventGridConnectionAPIName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "properties": {
            "api": {
                "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/', 'azureeventgrid')]"
            },
            "displayName": "[parameters('azureEventGridConnectionAPIName')]"
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    }
]
```

1. Am i missing something in the template that is responsible for authenticating the Connection right away?
2. Is there a way to authenticate that connection using for example Azure PowerShell so i can automate that process?

Comment: Are you using a service principal to authenticate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am i missing something in the template that is responsible for authenticating the Connection right away?

Yes, we could create a service principal authentication during deploy. Following is the demo code.

```
"resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('azureEventGridConnectionAPIName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/subscriptionId', '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', 'eastasia', '/managedApis/', 'azureeventgrid')]"

        },
        "parameterValues": {
          "token:clientId": "[parameters('clientId')]",
          "token:clientSecret": "[parameters('clientSecret')]",
          "token:TenantId": "[parameters('TenantId')]",
          "token:grantType": "[parameters('grantType')]"
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('azureEventGridConnectionAPIName')]"

      },
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ]
```

**Parameters.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "azureEventGridConnectionAPIName": {
      "value": "azureEventGridConnectionAPIName"
    },
    "clientId": {
      "value": "clientId"
    },
    "clientSecret": {
      "value": "secret key"
    },
    "TenantId": {
      "value": "tenant id"
    },
    "grantType": {
      "value": "client_credentials"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't quite get the idea of those service principal, even though i read about them. Is it like a set of rules, that i apply to the certain service, like in this example my API Connection? Also, could you explain what clientId and secret is? I figure it's the id and secret of something in the ADD, but what exactly?

Comment: The clientId is the  Azure AD application Id. secret is the  application secret key.  For more information please refer to [create service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application). We could assign the role to the application, then  service principal will get permissions to operate the azure resources.

Comment: So in this case, my EventGridAPIConnection is my "application"? I have to create it in ADD before the deployment, and then provide appID and secret as parameters?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. If you want to operate the azure resources don't forgot to assign role to the Azure AD application.

Comment: Could you explain what's "grantType" responsible for? If i set it to "client_credentials", my Connection is treated as sort of a user that identifies itself with clientId and secret? What are the other options, and how do i know which parametervalues a certain type of connection needs? I see that a blob storage connector has different parameterValues.

Comment: The` grant_type` URL parameter is required by OAuth2 RFC for the /token endpoint, which exchanges a grant for real tokens. For more information,please refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055277/what-is-the-purpose-of-grant-type-parameter-in-oauth-2-authentication). In my case, using the clientid and secert. So the grantType is `client_credentials`. You also could get more information from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as an answer. If you have any other questions, welcome to post a new SO thread.

Comment: `I see that a blob storage connector has different parameterValues.` Yes, different connectors has different parameterValues.

Comment: Yes, this has been very useful. I'm setting this as the answer. Thank you!