# How do I post Form Data with aiohttp?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, fastapi, aiohttp

I am testing making an OAuth server with FastAPI. I have one side, which is the Oauth server which has an endpoint that looks like:

```
@router.post("/token")
async def login_for_access_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()) -> Dict[str, str]:
    return {"access_token": form_data.username, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

And then on a separate process, I have a fake app with a log-in endpoint which looks like:

```
@router.post("/")
async def login(username: str, password: str) -> Dict[str, str]:

    form = OAuth2PasswordRequestForm(
        username=username,
        password=password,
        scope="me"
    )

    form_data = aiohttp.FormData()

    for key, val in form.__dict__.items():
        form_data.add_field(key, val)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(f"http://localhost:8001/oauth/token", data=form_data()) as server_response:
            response = await server_response.text()
            response = json.loads(response)
    return response
```

The OAuth server is responding with

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "grant_type"
      ],
      "msg": "string does not match regex \"password\"",
      "type": "value_error.str.regex",
      "ctx": {
        "pattern": "password"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I use aiohttp to post the form data to the oauth server?

Comment: It's complaining about the form data not including a `grant_type` key with the value `password`; it doesn't seem like you're including one with the data you're sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grant_type` field is missing from your data. Although `grant_type` is an optional field, as per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/simple-oauth2/#oauth2passwordrequestform) (have a look under the "Tip" section):

> The OAuth2 spec actually **requires** a field grant_type with a fixed
> value of `password`, but OAuth2PasswordRequestForm doesn't enforce it.
>
> If you need to enforce it, use OAuth2PasswordRequestFormStrict instead
> of OAuth2PasswordRequestForm.

Thus, your form should look like the one below. The `grant_type="password"` means that you are sending a username and a password to the `/token` endpoint (have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45060268) as well).

```
form = OAuth2PasswordRequestForm(
    grant_type="password",
    username=username,
    password=password,
    scope="me"
)
```